# VB Type Error With CreateParameter

Tags: asp-classic

So... I have the following in a function and whenever it gets called... I get a type error

`Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'`

Type mismatch: 'var'

```
dim conn, cmd, rs
set conn = GetConnection


''' Set the SQL based on request type '''
If isSubscriber = true Then
    execSQL = "select stuff from dbo.stuff WHERE field1 = 12" & _
         " AND email= @ParameterPwd" & _ 
         " AND password= @ParameterPwd" & _
         " AND EndDate >= GETDATE() "
Else
    execSQL = "select stuff from dbo.stuff2 WHERE field1 = 12" & _
         " AND email= @ParameterPwd" & _ 
         " AND password= @ParameterPwd" & _
         " AND EndDate >= GETDATE() "
End If

Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
''' Create the command with the appropriate SQL and params '''
With cmd
    .activeconnection=conn
    .commandtext= execSQL
    'Create the parameter (name,type,direction,size,value)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ParameterEmail", email)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ParameterPwd", pwd)
End With

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open cmd, conn

' Disconnect Recordset '
Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
set GetRecordSetSafeUser = rs
```

Error is happening on the following line:

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ParameterEmail", email)
```

by changing that line to the following:

```
.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ParameterEmail", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(email), email)
```

I get this error instead `Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.`

I have no idea why I'm getting this error. Not sure if my brain is fried or not. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues here:-

1. `var` is not a keyword in VBScript.  You need to use `Dim`
2. You cannot assign a value on the same line as the declaration. You need to separate these.
3. You have a stray asterisk (`*`) before your line continuation character `_` when assigning the SQL to `execSQL`.  This should be removed.
4. You are assigning the wrong parameter to the `email` in the `WHERE` clause.
5. You cannot use `adVarChar` and `adInputParameter` as these are not known. You need to substitute them with their numeric value.  Also for completeness and good practice, you should explicitly set the `CommandType` property on the `Command` object so that it is not "assumed" to be of type `adCommandText`.
6. You cannot set the connection object when opening the `Recordset` if you have already set it on the `Command` object

Here are MSDN links to show you the numeric values of your parameter enums:-

- DataTypeEnum: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675318(v=vs.85).aspx
- ParameterDirectionEnum: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678273(v=vs.85).aspx
- CommandType: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee266308(v=bts.10).aspx

Hope that helps.

```
Const adParamInput = 1
Const adVarChar = 200
Const adCmdText = 1

Dim execSQL
execSQL = ""
''' Set the SQL based on request type '''
If isSubscriber = true Then
    execSQL = "select stuff from dbo.stuff WHERE field1 = 12" _
         " AND email= @ParameterEmail" & _ 
         " AND password= @ParameterPwd" & _
         " AND EndDate >= GETDATE() "
Else
    execSQL = "select stuff from dbo.stuff2 WHERE field1 = 12"  _
         " AND email= @ParameterEmail" & _ 
         " AND password= @ParameterPwd" & _
         " AND EndDate >= GETDATE() "
End If
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
''' Create the command with the appropriate SQL and params '''
With cmd
    .activeconnection=conn
    .commandtype = adCmdText
    .commandtext= execSQL
    'Create the parameter (name,type,direction,size,value)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ParameterEmail", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(email), email)
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@ParameterPwd", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(pwd), pwd)
End With

set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open cmd
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually fixed that aspect of it. I will edit the question. Sorry about that. However, that isn't what is causing it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with number 5 to cover the next problem.

Comment: Damn, I think #5 may do it. If so... you'll be my hero!

Comment: Okay... it got a different error (which I'm happy about) `Cannot change the ActiveConnection property of a Recordset object which has a Command object as its source.`

Comment: I just figured that out as you added it LOL. Thank you so much. People like you make me smile!

Comment: I have updated #5 and the code regarding the `CommandType` property on the `Command` object.

Comment: Well done! However, I can't consider hard-coding the values of enumerated constants to be the best approach. For better readability and maintainability: you can always declare the appropriate constants in your declarations section of each script and then you can use enumerated types as you use them in C++ programs . For the current case: declaring `Const adVarChar=200, adParamInput=1`, you could keep the `.Parameters.Append.CreateParameter("@ParameterEmail", adVarChar, adParamInput, Len(email), email)` etc.

Comment: @JosefZ agreed. +1 for you!

Comment: Hi @JosefZ, I have updated my answer for completeness to include Constants as per your recommendation.

Comment: Good answer but point two while technically true you can short code it by using the `:` command separator character, like this `Dim execSQL: execSQL = ""`.

Comment: @JosefZ Better still you declare the [METADATA Type Library in `global.asa`](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml) and you never have to include them hard-coded or in an `#include` file again.

Comment: @JosefZ Given that this question is also tagged with VBScript (which does not have a global.asa), then this is not really an option.

Comment: @JosefZ, actually, I take my comment back.  This question should technically not be tagged with VBScript, as the code would not run when using `Server.CreateObject`.  VBScript would require `WScript.CreateObject`.  I am going to edit the question.